# How to use notification and accessing userInfo?

Tags: ios, swift3, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

I am working on a game of life project in Swift. I need to pass the grid via `NotificationCenter` to a `View Controller`. I am passing the info as follows:

```
let nc = NotificationCenter.default
let info = ["grid": self.grid]
nc.post(name: EngineNoticationName, object: nil, userInfo:info)
```

I am receiving the `Notification` in the `ViewController`. When I print out the userInfo with:

```
let grid = notified.userInfo?["grid"]
print("\(grid!)")
```

I get (it goes on for the 10x10 grid but I believe this is enough for my question):

> Grid(_cells: [[Assignment4.Cell(position: (row: 0, col: 0), state:
>   Assignment4.CellState.empty), Assignment4.Cell(position: (row: 0, col:
>   1), state: Assignment4.CellState.empty), Assignment4.Cell(position:
>   (row: 0, col: 2), state: Assignment4.CellState.empty),
>   Assignment4.Cell(position: (row: 0, col: 3), state:
>   Assignment4.CellState.empty), Assignment4.Cell(position: (row: 0, col:
>   4), state: Assignment4.CellState.empty), Assignment4.Cell(position:
>   (row: 0, col: 5), state: Assignment4.CellState.empty),
>   Assignment4.Cell(position: (row: 0, col: 6), state:
>   Assignment4.CellState.empty),

How can I access state in this object?

Thanks.

Comment: Cast `notified.userInfo?["grid"]` to `self.grid` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your notification handling function, you need to cast the received data as so:

```
func handleGridNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let grid = notification.userInfo["grid"] as? Grid {
        print(grid.cells[0][0].state)
    }
}
```

The above code should produce result: `Assignment4.CellState.empty`

I want also to adhere two things to your code:

1. A cell within array should not know about its' index. Consider leaving the Grid to handle changes in cell indices, or in other words you do not need this: `position: (row: 0, col: 1)`
2. For easier access to your custom object Grid you can create subscript method with 2 parameters matching the cells' array. E.G.: `grid[x][y]` could translate to `grid.cells[x][y]` , and this way cells could become `private` field. You can read more on this [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/123102/implementing-custom-subscripts-swift).

Comment: This got me to the answer. I had to use
    if let engine = notified.userInfo?["grid"] as? StandardEngine
Grid was a property of StandardEngine which contained the subscript method you described above. Thanks so much for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

As jack suggested cast it to grid type :

```
guard let grid = notified.userInfo?["grid"] as? gridType else {return}
//print(grid[0].state)
```